# Is this sentence necessarily too long

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, research

I am writing a research paper. It is about game design. Does this sentence *blabber* on?

> Throughout designing my game, I drew many concept pictures, but I would often go onto the Internet to search for images and videos of games that were currently on the market in order to compare them to the type of product I was aiming to create.

I feel as if it does.. :/

Comment: I'm not a gamer, so take that into consideration. *But* is a conjunction used to demonstrate a contrast: *I was hungry, but I did not eat.* *I was upset, but not as upset as I was when they found Lord Mountbatten's head and shoulders on the beach.* Your sentence is not too long, but I wonder if there is a demonstrated contrast after the *but*.

Comment: I suppose _'and'_ would be more appropriate

Comment: This is way too localized. It is not going to help anyone else, and is not even going to help yourself on other occasions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, your sentence isn't incorrect. However, you could make it shorter and more readable by cutting out redundant expressions. For instance, "Throughout," "in order to," "would often go onto," and "was aiming to" are examples of these expressions. By editing them out of your writing, you make the sentence easier to read.

Example:

> I drew many concept pictures while designing my game; I would search the Internet for images and videos of games that were currently on the market and compare them to the type of product I was creating.

Comment: Thanks. When I read it aloud, it did seem really odd, but this has helped. I can't +1, yet, so I will when I can! :D

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Throughout the design of my project, I would often go to the Internet to search for images and videos of games that are currently on the market.  I would use these images to compare them to the type of product I was aiming to create.

OR

While I drew many concept pictures, I often felt is helpful to go to the internet and look at images of video games that are currently on the market.

Answer (score 0):

It's way, way, way too long.  And, you are babbling on about nothing.

Just DIRECTLY SAY what you're trying to say.

A lot of it is just crap.  You don't have to explain you were looking for "images and videos" (what else would you be looking for?)  Since, say, 20 years now you don't have to explain "on the internet!"  (How else would you do it? an extranet?  Psychic powers?)

Try to say what you mean. Something more like "When I was designing the game, I had to keep looking at other games being launched."

note that I still know **nothing** about what you actually mean.

"in order to compare them to the type of product I was aiming to create"

Why?

What do you mean "compare"?  Who gives a shit about games on the market?  Do you mean you wanted to **avoid doing something similar to...** or in contrast do you mean you **wanted to do something like whatever was selling well..**

Were you talking about new games being released, or existing popular games, or flops, or hits, or ?

or what?

Comment: the essay is an ICT based report. Meaning we have to talk about how we used technology (and what technology (in this case the Internet)).. I have to talk about images and videos because I could have looked at online games, or pod-casts, anything. I have to be specific. Thanks for your input, but I've already changed this thread to _answered_

Answer (score 0):

> Throughout designing my game, I drew many concept pictures, but I
>   would often go onto the Internet to search for images and videos of
>   games that were currently on the market in order to compare them to
>   the type of product I was aiming to create.

When designing my game, I drew many (of my own) concept pictures. But I would also go onto the Internet frequently, searching for images and videos of games already on the market. I compared those designs to my own...

You cannot "compare" those designs to something that does not yet exist ("the type of product I was aiming to create"). Also you cannot compare an object to a class of object. Comparands must have the same existential status. You could "assess" those images and videos or "evaluate" them for their appropriateness to what you had in mind.  But strictly speaking you cannot *compare* them to an inchoate idea still taking shape in your mind.

You'd have to say something like, "I compared those designs to my own, and assessed whether they (or their style) would be suitable for what I was aiming to create.